# Writing a method that will accept table as an input

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to write a method that can accept a table as input, i.e.:

```
void Take_something_from_table(string table_name)
{
  DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();              
  var queryResult = from a in dc.GetTable<*table_name*>()  //without * of course 
                    select a;

  ...
}
```

I want a method that will be called `Take_something_from_table(Test_table)`

I tried this and got this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'table_name' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

HELP!!

Comment: Why do you need to use a string?  Just give it the entity type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i agree with leppie, or if u wana keep that string as table name then define and enum or else and place If Else block to perform action.
for example

```
if(TabmeNameA)
{
   // Execute Query for table A
}
if(TabmeNameB)
{
   // Execute Query for table B
}
```

Comment: it doesn't have to be string... I used it for example only.